# Checkout session return 0 in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, session, coupon-codes

i am facing an issue in checkout session in version 1.9.2.4.
using

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
                    ->getQuote()
                    ->setCouponCode($coupon)
                     ->collectTotals()
                        ->save();
```

code i am trying to set coupon code programmatically, it does work in older version but not in magento version 1.9.2.4.
if i print

```
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
```

it returns 0 while cart have item. 
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
array_sum(Mage::getModel('Quote/Address')->getAllTotalAmounts());
```

**Hope it will help you**